# Http Web Request Errors in UWP Application

Tags: c#, .net, http, httprequest, uwp

I am using the Microsoft Translator API in .NET UWP application and I'm following the steps for obtaining an access token from the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I copied the code into my project, but I'm getting errors on the HttpWebRequest GetRequestStream() and GetResponse() methods saying it does not contain a definition for those.  I believe the issue is that I'm using a UWP application since I tried it out in a console application and it worked.

Does anyone know how I can get this code to work in my UWP application? TIA.

```
private AdmAccessToken HttpPost(string DatamarketAccessUri, string requestDetails)
    {
        //Prepare OAuth request 
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(DatamarketAccessUri);
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestDetails);
        //webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream outputStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AdmAccessToken));
            //Get deserialized object from JSON stream
            AdmAccessToken token = (AdmAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            return token;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
The errors that I was getting for the above code were fixed when I followed the checked answer.  However, there's still one more error that I'm trying to fix - I followed the response in the comments below, and while the errors went away, the code exits at the line

```
 WebResponse response = await translationWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

Relevant code posted below:

```
 //Exits on the WebResponse line
 private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DetectMethod(string authToken, AdmAccessToken token, string txtToTranslate)
    {
        string headerValue = "Bearer " + token.access_token;
        string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(txtToTranslate) + "&from=en&to=es";

        WebRequest translationWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        translationWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = headerValue;
        WebResponse response = await translationWebRequest.GetResponseAsync(); //where it's exiting
        System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        System.IO.StreamReader translatedStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode);
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ReadToEnd());
        translatedText = xTranslation.InnerText;
        return null;
    }

 //Where DetectMethod is called from
 public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> Translate(string TextToTranslate)
    {
        AdmAccessToken admToken;
        string headerValue;

        AdmAuthentication admAuth = new AdmAuthentication("<>", "<>");//codes removed
        try
        {
            admToken = admAuth.GetAccessToken();
            // Create a header with the access_token property of the returned token
            headerValue = "Bearer " + admToken.access_token;
            await DetectMethod(headerValue, admToken, TextToTranslate); //calls previous method
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            ProcessWebException(e);
        }
        return translatedText;
    }
```

The method that calls upon Translate() method also has await for calling the method and async in its signature.  Again, with these changes, there are no more errors, but the program exits at the WebResponse line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I copied the code into my project, but I'm getting errors on the HttpWebRequest GetRequestStream() and GetResponse() methods saying it does not contain a definition for those. I believe the issue is that I'm using a UWP application since I tried it out in a console application and it worked.

Yes,UWP is targeting .Net Core while console application is targeting normal .Net Framework.

Instead of `GetRequestStream` and `GetResponse` you can use the async version like below:

```
//mark the method as async
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<AdmAccessToken> HttpPost(string DatamarketAccessUri, string requestDetails)
{
    ...
    //use 'GetRequestStreamAsync'
    using (Stream outputStream =await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    {
        ...
    }
    //use 'GetResponseAsync' instead
    using (WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        ...
        return token;
    }
}
```

**Update:** I made a demo using translator API. Here are the codes:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Name="myBtn" Click="myBtn_Click">Click Me</Button>
        <TextBlock Name="myTB"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void myBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var translatedText = await Translate("Text for test");
        myTB.Text = translatedText;
    }

    //Exits on the WebResponse line
    private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> DetectMethod(string authToken, AdmAccessToken token, string txtToTranslate)
    {
        string headerValue = "Bearer " + token.access_token;
        string uri = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(txtToTranslate) + "&from=en&to=es";

        WebRequest translationWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        translationWebRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = headerValue;
        WebResponse response = await translationWebRequest.GetResponseAsync(); //where it's exiting
        System.IO.Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        System.IO.StreamReader translatedStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream, encode);
        System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
        xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ReadToEnd());
        //translatedText = xTranslation.InnerText;
        return xTranslation.InnerText;
    }

    //Where DetectMethod is called from
    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> Translate(string TextToTranslate)
    {
        AdmAccessToken admToken;
        string headerValue;
        string translatedText=null;
        AdmAuthentication admAuth = new AdmAuthentication("<>", "<>");//codes removed
        try
        {
            admToken =await admAuth.GetAccessToken();
            // Create a header with the access_token property of the returned token
            headerValue = "Bearer " + admToken.access_token;
            translatedText= await DetectMethod(headerValue, admToken, TextToTranslate); //calls previous method
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {

        }
        return translatedText;
    }

    public class AdmAccessToken
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string scope { get; set; }

    }
    public class AdmAuthentication
    {
        string clientID = "winffee_4960";
        string clientSecret = "N0aTQ4OUKKP5lpNIBs0h9wfFXGpHlel1BpIkmDd1cVE=";
        String strTranslatorAccessURI = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
        String strRequestDetails;
        public AdmAuthentication(String str1, String str2)
        {
            strRequestDetails= string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com", WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientID), WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

        }
        public async Task<AdmAccessToken> GetAccessToken()
        {
            WebRequest webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(strTranslatorAccessURI);
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strRequestDetails);
            //webRequest.ContentType = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream outputStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AdmAccessToken));
            //Get deserialized object from JSON stream 
            AdmAccessToken token = (AdmAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string headerValue = "Bearer " + token.access_token;
            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question - there's one more error on the GetResponse() method: `WebResponse response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();`
Do I need to do the async there as well? I also found something about using an HTTP client instead - so which way is the correct way to go?

Comment: **Update**: I tried following using GetResponseAsync() in the same way as above, but it no longer works when I did that. I also tried using a code from elsewhere that used HTTP client, but that didn't work either

Comment: Did you add `await` in front of GetResponseAsync()?  And when this method is called, await should also be added like this: `AdmAccessToken token= await HttpPost(arg1,arg2)`.

Comment: Yes, and I added the await in front of the method that is calling it, but it exits out at the same WebResponse line above. I'm going to copy the relevant parts of the code in an update to my question above

Comment: I see, you are using Microsoft Translator API. I made a demo with your codes also using Translator API. But it didn't hang. You can find my demo here: [TranslatorAPIDemo](https://github.com/elvisxia/TranslatorAPI_Demo).

Comment: It won't let me open it. When I download it, it says "Resource not available for anonymous access"

Comment: I guess we are using different versions of VS. I'm using VS2015. I'll post the codes. Please check update.

Comment: When I test that one out, but replace the button event with a displaying it on the console for quick results, it times out at `using (Stream outputStream = await webRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync())` in the `GetAccessToken()` method.

Comment: It could be the reason of the bad internet connection. Could you please try catching the data package using fiddler.

Comment: Using fiddler, I can see that it does not go through when running my program as is.  However, when I remove the await from the WebResponse line (so that it's `WebResponse response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();`), it works, but my goal is for it to be compatible in my UWP program, which is the reason for using async, as you initially pointed out.
(Again, I am testing in .NET 4 so I can see the results on the console, but I want my program to be compatible in .NET Core and there is an error on that line without using async.)

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other suggestions, been racking my brains on this one

Comment: Could you maybe share a demo project that can reproduce this problem?I'll check if I can produce the problem in my computer.

Comment: I created a dropbox link for you to download view the project: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg9fq3hgpka8xsp/Translator.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Sorry for late response, I checked your demo project. I reproduced the problem. Currently I can't find the reason. But this problem seems only exists in .Net project. In WinRT Project everything works fine. So, if you are developing a UWP project. Go ahead and use this method.